# Flutter is not rebuilding same widget with different parameters

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I was working with bottom navigation with similar child widgets in which only parameters are changed. The problem only happens when widgets are of **StatefulWidget** else  there is no problem, indications in bottomnavbar is changing but not the body.

**Child 1:**
[image]

**Child 2:**
[image]

**Actual result:**
[image]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
final String title;

@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
int _counter = 0;
Widget body;
@override
void initState() {
//    body = getBody(0);
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
    elevation: 0,
  ),
  body: body,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: _counter,
    onTap: (index){
      _counter = index;
      setState(() {
        body = getBody(index);
      });
    },items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.language),title: 
 Text('HELLO')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.security),title: 
Text('BYE'))
  ]),
 );
}
Widget getBody(int pos){
if(pos==0){
//      return new Mx(category: 'ALPHA',type: '@',);
  return new MyTAbs(category: 'ALPHA',type: '@',);
}
else{
//      return new Mx(category:'BETA',type: '#',);
  return new MyTAbs(category:'BETA',type: '#',);
  }
 }
}
class Mx extends StatelessWidget{
final String type,category;
Mx({this.type,this.category});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: getColor(),
  body: new Center(
    child: Text(category+' '+type),
  ),
 );
}
Color getColor(){
if(category=='ALPHA'){
  return Colors.red;
}
else{
  return Colors.green;
  }
 }
}
class MyTAbs extends StatefulWidget{
final String type,category;
MyTAbs({this.type,this.category});
Tabs createState() => new Tabs(title: category,type: type);
}
class Tabs extends State<MyTAbs>{
final String title,type;
Tabs({this.title,this.type});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: getColor(),
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(title+' '+type),
  ),
);
}
Color getColor(){
if(title=='ALPHA'){
  return Colors.red;
}
else{
  return Colors.green;
  }
 }
}
```

and I can't use **statelessWidget** because there's a dynamic tab section inside.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Solved this issue by adding new Key as parameter and passed a **UniqueKey** 
like

```
return new MyTAbs(category: 'ALPHA',type: '@',key: UniqueKey(),);
```

MyTAbs class

```
class MyTAbs extends StatefulWidget{
  final String type,category;
  final Key key;
  MyTAbs({@required this.key,this.type,this.category});
  Tabs createState() => new Tabs(title: category,type: type,key: key);
}
```

Tabs class

```
class Tabs extends State<MyTAbs>{
  final String title,type;
  final Key key;
  Tabs({this.title,this.type,@required this.key});
  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: getColor(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title+' '+type),
      ),
    );
  }
  Color getColor(){
    if(title=='ALPHA'){
      return Colors.red;
    }
    else{
      return Colors.green;
    }
  }
}
```

little about **Key**

*You can use keys to control which widgets the framework matches up with other widgets when a widget rebuilds. By default, the framework matches widgets in the current and previous build according to their runtimeType and the order in which they appear. With keys, the framework requires that the two widgets have the same key as well as the same runtimeType.* [more in flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro#keys)

Comment: Thanks a lot, stuck today with the same problem. I thought, if one of parameters has been changed, the Widget will be rebuilt, but not, initState() has not been called. UniqKey() worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Tabs` class

```
class Tabs extends State<MyTAbs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: getColor(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.category + ' ' + widget.type),
      ),
    );
  }

  Color getColor() {
    if (widget.category == 'ALPHA') {
      return Colors.red;
    } else {
      return Colors.green;
    }
  }
}
```

Class `State` (`Tabs`) created only once. So after that you can't call constructor with new parameters. But you have access to the widgets' fields

Answer (score 1):

your problem in "MyTAbs" passing parameters class

after edit it , now its work

you dont need to pass the date from "Stateful" class to the "State", just call it with "widget.parameterName" in the state
your code after edit :

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Widget body;
  @override
  void initState() {
//    body = getBody(0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: body,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _counter,
          onTap: (index){
            _counter = index;
            setState(() {
              body = getBody(index);
            });
          },items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.language),title:
        Text('HELLO')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.security),title:
        Text('BYE'))
      ]),
    );
  }
  Widget getBody(int pos){
    if(pos==0){
//      return new Mx(category: 'ALPHA',type: '@',);
      return new MyTAbs(category: 'ALPHA',type: '@',);
    }
    else{

//      return new Mx(category:'BETA',type: '#',);
      return new MyTAbs(category:'BETA',type: '#',);
    }
  }
}
class Mx extends StatelessWidget{
  final String type,category;
  Mx({this.type,this.category});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: getColor(),
      body: new Center(
        child: Text(category+' '+type),
      ),
    );
  }
  Color getColor(){
    if(category=='ALPHA'){
      return Colors.red;
    }
    else{
      return Colors.green;
    }
  }
}
class MyTAbs extends StatefulWidget{
  final String type,category;
  MyTAbs({this.type,this.category});
  Tabs createState() => new Tabs();
}
class Tabs extends State<MyTAbs>{


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.type);
// TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: getColor(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.category+' '+widget.type),
      ),
    );
  }
  Color getColor(){
    if(widget.category=='ALPHA'){
      return Colors.red;
    }
    else{
      return Colors.green;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @abdalmonem your answer is correct but in my case I'm loading tabs inside Tabs class so can't use yours instead i added a key as parameter as mentioned above. Your answer is a new info for me.